# Setting text with two different font size on JButton

Tags: java, swing

I have to make an on screen keyboard for a swing application. In that I need to write text with different font size on the same JButton. I want to make keyboard like in smartphones.

for example:
jButton.setText(1(font size 30) ABC(font size 10));
As in the above example I want to set "1" with font size 30 and "ABC" with font size 0f 10.

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML as text. Something like this:

```
    button.setText("<html><font size=\"1\">small</font> <font size=\"7\">huge</font></html>");
```

Comment: I tried this but not working.